# Opening file initially created in Excel 2003 in Excel 2016 (VBA macros included)

Tags: excel, vba

I've a problem with an Excel file created under version 2003.

Using Excel version 2016, I tried to open this file, but an error message from VBA appeared:

> Run-time error '57121' Application-defined or object-defined error

Seems `Worksheets("...").Activate` is causing the problem.

It is a Workbook_Open code

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, l As Integer, ws As Worksheet, rs As QueryTable
Worksheets("Summary").Activate
Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).RefreshAll
Worksheets("Summary").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Folderpath = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Backup\ & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Range("D2").Value & "\"
Filepath = "Test " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Range("D2").Value & ".xls"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks.Open (Folderpath & Filepath), UpdateLinks:=False
end sub
```

All is working for Excel 2003, but not in Excel 2016

Comment: Sounds like there is an `Auto_Open` or `Workbook_Open` subroutine. What exactly is it doing? More code would be helpful.

Comment: Hold down shift while opening the file - that should prevent any code from being triggered by the Open event.  Would be helpful to post more of the code if you're still having problems.